# added own icons to customized ribbon in access - they just dont show

Tags: icons, customization, ribbon

There is a fine how-to-do for customized ribbons with own Icons in Access: http://www.accessribbon.de/?Access_-_Ribbons:Eigene_Icons___Bilder_in_Ribbon_Controls_verwenden

I follwed it - just the Icons dont show.

Button using imageMso works fine, button using getImage does not:

```
<button id="btnFrmPersonenOeffen1" 
        label="Personen" 
        imageMso="AccessFormDatasheet" 
        onAction="FormOpen" /> 
<button id="btnFrmPersonenOeffen2" 
        label="Personen" 
        size="large" 
        getImage="getImages" 
        tag="IBU.ico" 
        onAction="FormOpen" />
```

Added some test in the getImages() procedure:

```
Public Sub getImages(control As IRibbonControl, _
                     ByRef image)
Dim t As String
   t  = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\" & control.Tag
   MsgBox t, , "pic found: [" & Dir(t) & "]"
   Set image = LoadPicture(t)
End Sub
```

even tried referring to a non-existent Picture in the tag-entry to make sure it causes an error message - as it did.
Referred to different Icons of different sizes.
Changed size from "normal" to "large" - space provided in the button changed - just the referred Icon does't Show up. There's empty space shown:

(added screenshot but it was removed)

Comment: Lately found: if you use pictures in jpg-format, they actually do show up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't get any UI errors, see [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This is a quite valuable hint - thanks! But as I'm a feared specialist in omitting comma and things like that, activating Add-In User Interface Errors (AIUIE) had do be done some time ago already :-)    So I found: even IF there ARE errors (Like pointing to an Image, that doesn't exist or having a path-error it doesn't Show up as a  AIUIE  - as Long as it is done syntactically right. My own icons assigned to a button are loaded when I first open the ribbon tab they are expected to show up. Only then the procedure  referred to  in  getImage="getImages"   is executed.

Comment: (continuing my previous comment)  This enables me to put up my own Little error trap, assinging name and location of my own Icons to a variable and simply testing for accessability in a messagebox :  Public Sub getImages(control As IRibbonControl, _
                     ByRef image)
'
Dim sImageSpec As String
   
   sImageSpec = Application.CurrentProject.path _
              & "\..\image\" & control.Tag
   MsgBox t, , "pic found: [" & Dir(t) & "]"
  '
   Set image = LoadPicture(sImageSpec)
  '
End Sub

Comment: (Sorry, didn't manage to have the code broken propperly)   So my littel trick with looking for the Image in the "LoadImages"-Sub showed two things: Icons were found, space in front or on top the button was allocated, but Icons didn't Show. If I referred to a file, that didn't exist or committed a path-error, here was no  AIUIE-Alarm  but a message like "Access was not able to open file "blablabla".

Comment: Only thing I found out when finally stepping away from what I had found on the internet was: pointing to a JPG does the Job.   (Sadly by then I already had bothered this community with my question)

Comment: What I still don't know:  Can user-defined Icons in user customized ribbons in access only use JPG-Format or where am I still doing wrong with ICO-Format?

Comment: You need to use png images for ribbon controls.